# Selenium test cases are failed for a modal popup window

Tags: selenium, testing, dialog, modal-dialog

All Test cases fail after execution of a test case where a redirection to CRM URL is present. It opens the URL in the browser with a credential popup of crm. It says the following message

```
"An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.UnhandledAlertException' occurred in WebDriver.dll 
but was not handled in user code  Additional information: Modal dialog present".
```

I have used the below code to handle the issue. But it is not working.
Code snippet I used:

```
String mainWindowHandle = Driver.CurrentWindowHandle.ToString();
        ReusableFuncPage.GetTxtfirstname().SendKeys(Keys.Enter);           
        Driver.SwitchTo().Window(mainWindowHandle);
```

How do I close the credential Modal dialog and return to the parent window to continue the rest of test  cases?

Comment: how many window are opened when you run the script?

Comment: @SarithaG -  One window for CRM URL with a Windows Credential "Modal dialog".

Comment: first switch to alert using:  Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();,  then close the alert: alert.dismiss(); after closing alert,switch to your parent window.